# 3D Affine transformation problem in raytracing

Tags: math, raytracing, matrix-multiplication, montecarlo, affinetransform

All,

I am writing a rather non conventional ray tracer to calculate heat transfer properties of various objects in a scene. In this ray tracer random rays are shot from the surface of my primitive objects into a scene to check for intersections.

This particular algorithm requires each ray to be developed in primitive space then affine transformed by the source object into world space then subsequently affine transformed back into the primitive space of other objects in the scene to check for intersection.

All is good until I do a anisotropic scale for example scaling a object by [2 2 1] (isotropic scales are fine). This leads me to believe I am not transforming the directional component of the ray correctly. Currently I transform the ray direction from primitive space to world space by multiplying the directional component by the transpose of the source objects inverse transformation matrix and then I transform the ray from world space to each primitive space by multiplying by the transpose of the destination objects transformation matrix.

I have also tried multiplying by the source primitive's transformation matrix to go from primitive to world space and multiplying by the the destinations inverse transformation to go from world space to primitive space but this was unsuccessful.

I believe a ray launched from the surface of a primitive object (at a random point and in a random direction) should be transformed in the same manner as a surface normal in 'regular' ray tracing however I am not certain.

Any of the experts out there know what the flaw in my methodology is? Feel free to ask if more information is required.

---

The basic algorithm for this ray tracer is as follows:

```
For each object, i, in scene
{
    for each ray, r, in number of rays per object
    {
        determine random ray from primitive i
        convert ray from primitive space of i to world space

        for each object, j, in scene
        {
            convert ray to primitive space of object j
            check for intersection with object j
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully to clear up the question lets look at an example. Lets assume I have a cylinder extending along the z-axis (unit radius and height) and an annulus lying in the x-y plane with inner diameter 7 and outer diameter 8.  I want the scale the cylinder by a factor 6 in the x and y directions (but not the z direction) so my affine transformation matrix are as follows:

```
M(cylinder) = |2 0 0 0|        M^-1(cylinder) = | .5 0. 0. 0. |
              |0 2 0 0|                         | 0. .5 0. 0. |
              |0 0 1 0|                         | 0. 0. 1. 0. |
              |0 0 0 1|                         | 0. 0. 0. 1. |

M(annulus) =  |1 0 0 0|        M^-1(annulus) =  |1 0 0 0|
              |0 1 0 0|                         |0 1 0 0|
              |0 0 1 0|                         |0 0 1 0|
              |0 0 0 1|                         |0 0 0 1|
```

Now assume I have a ray which has a random starting point on the surface of the cylinder s and a random direction away from the surface of the cylinder c giving the ray r(os) = s + ct.

I want to transform this ray from primitive (object) space to world space and then test for intersection with the other objects in the scene (the annulus).

The first question is what is the correct way to transform the ray, r(os), to world space, r(ws), using M(cylinder) or M^-1(cylinder).

The second question is what is the correct way to then transform the ray, r(ws), from world space to object space to check for intersection with the other objects using M(annulus) and M^-1(annulus).

---

Some additional background information:

This application is for calculating radiative heat transfer between N objects. The ray is launched from a random point on the object with its direction being randomly selected to lie within a hemispherical distribution orientated with the surface normal at the random point.

---

Here is some visualisation of my problem. The ray directional distribution when it is first generated:
[image: Initial ray directional distribution]

If I apply the transformation to world co-ordinates using the transformation matrix M:
[image: Direction transformed by M]

If I apply the transformation to world co-ordinates using the inversetransformation matrix M^-1
[image: Direction transformed by M^-1]

Comment: This sentence is hardly comprehensible: "Now this particular algorithm calls for the ray to be determined in primitive space then affine transformed by the source object into world space then affine transformed back into the primitive space of the other objects in the scene to check for intersection."   Also, can you explain **why** you do what you do in the second paragraph.  Some more explanation and math is needed here to even try to help you.

Comment: i was thinking it might be helpful if you encoded your statements about your algorithm into mathematical formulae or code, just to be clear about order of multiplications etc.

Comment: Also, wait a second.  I don't see how this is related to C++ directly.  It sounds strictly like a math problem.

Comment: Is your transformation matrix a linear transform from primitive to world space and vice-versa?  I don't see why you need the transpose of the transformation matrix unless your transformation matricies are orthonormal.  Otherwise for a linear transformation matrix A, A(INV)*A*x=x for a given vector x.  You must be introducing some type of non-linear transform for this relationship to break.  For instance, are you also dealing with translations in your transformation matricies, and if so, are you using a homogeneous coordinate system?

Comment: Chris that is correct it does not have anything to do with C++ I have removed the tag. Originally I was going to approach it through code (it is written in C++) but decided I didn't need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just came up the other day in [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647265/help-me-solve-this-bug-with-my-ray-tracer/5707727#comment-6622038)

One of the answers links to a Ray Tracing News article discussing the use of the transpose of the inverse transform for normals.

I have to agree with JCooper in asking "what is actually going wrong?". My first thought is that you seem to be simulating radiated heat transfer, and you have to be careful will non-uniform scaling of objects. If you have a uniform distribution of "photons" on an objects surface being emitted, and then you apply a non-uniform scaling of that object, you will then have a non-uniform distribution of photons leaving the surface. This is one possible pitfall, but since you don't indicate what's going wrong it's hard to say if this is your problem.

To answer your questions about the correct way to do the transformations, follow [This link to Ray Tracing News](http://tog.acm.org/resources/RTNews/html/rtnews1a.html#art4)

Comment: phkahler, Your are very correct I am modelling radiative heat transfer and my problem is that my uniform distribution of 'photons' becomes non uniform after anisotropy scaling. So in essence I need to know how to transform from object space to world space and from world space to object space to preserve the uniform distribution.

Comment: If you put uniformly distributed points on the surface of a cube and then stretch it vertically by 2x, the points on the top and bottom don't change density while the sides get half the density. This same problem exists on a sphere. I'm sure there are solutions, but I don't think it's not a problem with the transformation itself.

Answer (score 3):

The inverse transpose transformation matrix keeps the rotation component constant, but inverts the scaling.  That means that the scaling is still there.  This is correct for normals: Consider, in 2d, a line segment from **(0,0)** to **(.707,.707)**.  The normal is **(-.707,.707)**.  If we scale by **(s,1)**, we get a segment from **(0,0)** to **(s*.707,.707)**.  In the limit, as **s** grows large, we essentially have a flat line parallel to the x axis.  That means that the normal should point along the y axis.  So we get a normal of **(-.707/s,.707)**.  It should be clear from this example, however, that the transformed vector is no longer unit length.  Perhaps you need to normalize the directional component?

If we start by using the property that a transformation matrix can be represented as a scaling sandwiched between two rotations (a la SVD), we get your outbound transformation matrix looks like so: **R2out*Sout^-1*R1out** and then your inbound transformation matrix looks like so: **R1in^-1*Sin*R2in^-1** (how I wish SO used Mathjax...).  This seems like the right thing, as long as you re-normalize your vectors.

---

Edit:

Thinking about this overnight, I decided that the inverse-transpose thing might *only* be valid for the normals case.  Consider the example above.  If **s=2**, then the slope of the line-segment, originally **1**, turns into **1/2**.  Likewise, the slope of the normal turns from **-1** into **-2**.  There's still a 90 degree angle between the line segment and the ray.  So far so good.  Now... what if the vector under consideration is actually parallel to the line segment.  We get a slope of **2**, no longer parallel.

So, I guess I have two questions at this point.  What is actually *going wrong* in your program/What makes you think it's not correct?  And what is the *correct* behavior?  Perhaps you can make a 2D plot.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your terminology for the outbound and inbound transformations. I have looked at normalising the directional vectors. Info I have says that if you normalise than your intersection times (t) will be wrong.

Comment: I agree with JCooper, there is probably a non-linearity being introduced somewhere. If you are appending multiple transformations the order is important (i.e. I think I'm right in saying you probably want to scale first, then rotate and then translate into position). If you want you could use my ray tracing code as a reference, you can create cylinders, transformations and check for ray intersections simply in a few lines written in a python shell https://github.com/danieljfarrell/pvtrace let me know if you need guidance.

Comment: In the cases I am running I am either only scaling or scaling and transforming (in that order) so the order should not be an issue. I'm not sure where the non-linearity would be introduced.

Comment: JCooper here is more background. My code actually calculates a thing called the view factor which is how much a surface can see of another surface. The view factor from surface i to surface j, Fij, is calculated as the number of rays leaving i that hit j / the total number of rays leaving i. Now I am testing this [link](http://www.engr.uky.edu/rtl/Catalog/sectionc/C-77.html) scene. When no scaling (or isotropic) is used I get the correct result, but if I scale by the [2 2 1] I get an incorrect result. Transforming by M I get a lower result, transforming by M^-1 I get a higher result.

Comment: @TDawg So you do a Monte Carlo simulation to approximate the view factor?  That would mean that rays need to be randomly sampled from surface of cylinder _after_ scaling, in order to avoid making the sample non-uniform, right?

Comment: JCooper thats correct the rays need to be randomly sampled from the surface after scaling. The ray position scales correctly but I think after scaling of the directions they no longer sit on uniformly on a hemisphere.